# PHP script returns no data form remote server

Tags: php, sql

I have a PHP script to pull data from a remote server. If a valid argument is passed when the script is called the correct data is retuned. I have an *else* statement that will return all rows if the argument passed  is invalid or null:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET'){
   if (isset($_GET['departmentName'])){
         //Fetch all rows with departName passed to GET call
         $department = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['departmentName']);
         $sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE departmentName = '$department'");
         $data = $sql->fetch_assoc();//return row /s as an array

     }else {
         //If deprtmentname not found retun all rows
       $data = array();
         $sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table");
         while($d = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
             //add every row $d returned to teh data array
             $data[] = $d;
         }
     }

     //Reunr the JSON reprsenation of the data; if one row its an JSON object only
     exit(json_encode($data));

}
```

I have little experience  with PHP but my understanding is *isset* checks whether a variable has been passed to a script and is not NULL, therefore if this check fails the *else* statement should execute and return all rows from the table.

For example the following correctly returns all rows under *Biochemistry*:

```
http://localhost/crud_api/api/contacts.php/?departmentName=Biochemistry
```

However nothing is returned when I pass either an invalid argument (a departmentName that does not exist) or if I do not pass a value.

```
http://localhost/crud_api/api/contacts.php/
```

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Be warned: the given SQL statement is widely open for SQL injection. Better have a look at prepared statements

Comment: Thanks - yes I plan to, this script is running on a local machine until its ready

Comment: Also, what have you tried to debug the problem? `http://localhost/crud_api/api/contacts.php/departmentName=Biochemistry`  does not look like the usual way to build a GET request, better use a `?` after `contacts.php`

Comment: "Running on a local machine" is not a good reason to write insecure code - I hope you have enough unit tests to ensure that your application still works after fixing such issues?

Comment: This is not about prepared statements, I am running through a tutorial and have come into the issue with  the PHP script in same

Comment: Why bother mark the question down? Do you have a suggestion that might help ? If  not just leave it

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior using a slightly modified version of your script (keeping intact the core control flow) in [this Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/UnselfishDetailedRay#index.php). ([Department name not set](https://UnselfishDetailedRay.esqew.repl.co)) ([Department name set to `a`](https://unselfishdetailedray.esqew.repl.co/index.php?departmentName=a))

Comment: @esqew That URL syntax should work. Everything after the `.php` is put in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

Comment: @Barmar Interesting, that'd be a TIL for me. Is there any documentation on that?

Comment: @esqew https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: @Barmar Thanks - I stand corrected.

Comment: But just in case your webserver isn't configured to allow the PHP script in the middle of the URL, does it work if you remove the `/` after `.php`?

Comment: @Barmar yes works with '/' removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this solution is useful for those, like me,  new to PHP and in particular debugging in PHP.

I added following to my script for debugging:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

And changed :

```
exit(json_encode($data));
```

To:

```
exit(json_encode($data, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR, 512));
```

The error was now visible in the POSTMAN console (prior to these changes there was no visible error thrown in the console):

> Fatal error: Uncaught JsonException: Malformed UTF-8 characters,
> possibly incorrectly encoded in myDirectory/contacts.php:80 Stack
> trace: #0  myDirectory/contacts.php(80): json_encode(Array, 4194304,
> 512) #1 {main}   thrown in  myDirectory//contacts.php on line 80

I narrowed this down to an apostrophe in a field entry in the database.
Removed same and its working fine.

For the downvotes- please  provide feedback that might be useful, otherwise its like a broken pencil, pointless :)